# How to apply abort filter on PCAP?

Tags: wireshark, packet, pcap, ss7

I am using pcap4j for reading packets in Java. I want to generate an alert on receiving a packet with abort. For now I am unable to apply a filter for abort. I have attached  code below.

```
    PcapHandle handle;
    Pcap pcap;
    handle = 

  Pcaps.openOffline("D://nm_postpaid_testing.pcap",TimestampPrecision.NANO);

    //handle.setFilter("tcap.reason == 11", BpfCompileMode.OPTIMIZE);
    System.out.println("Starting output: ");

    PcapPacket packet = null;


    String filter = "pcap abort 11";
    handle.setFilter(filter, BpfCompileMode.OPTIMIZE);
    PacketListener listener = new PacketListener() {
        @Override
        public void gotPacket(PcapPacket pp) {

            System.out.println("/////////////START////////////////");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pp.getRawData()));

            SctpDecoder sctpDecoder = new SctpDecoder();

            //sctpDecoder.decode(pp.getRawData(), "IP", "*", true, "DECODE:TCAP");

            System.out.println("///////////////END//////////////\n");

        }
    };

    handle.loop(4, listener);
```

[image]

Comment: I think the text you are using for your filter, "pcap abort 11", is invalid.
If I'm not mistaking, this page describes the allowed syntax:
https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filtering that can be done by pcap libraries (libpcap/WinPcap/Npcap) is very limited; it can't test for anything as complicated as a TCAP abort.  You'd have to dissect the packets in detail, either by writing your own code or by somehow using Wireshark/TShark/sharkd's code, to determine whether the packet you have is a TCP abort.

Comment: Can you please explain what is tshark or sharkd??

Comment: They're programs that come with Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

#### Invalid Capture Filter

The capture filter `pcap abort 11` is not valid (line 13). You can test this with `dumpcap -d -f "<filter>"` like so:

```sh
bash-5.0$ dumpcap -d -f "pcap abort 11"
Capturing on 'Wi-Fi: en0'
dumpcap: Invalid capture filter "pcap abort 11" for interface 'en0'.

That string isn't a valid capture filter (syntax error in filter expression: syntax error).
See the User's Guide for a description of the capture filter syntax.
```

If it's valid, dumpcap will show you the BPF instructions for the filter.

You have a `tcap.reason == 11` (line 7), which is valid, and you may want to reuse that as applicable.

Comment: `tcap.reason == 11` works in wire-shark but it gives following error in my code.
`Exception in thread "main" org.pcap4j.core.PcapNativeException: Error occurred in pcap_compile: can't parse filter expression: syntax error`

Comment: That sounds like a problem with pcap4j. I might go with @VasilVelichkov's suggestion to try using tshark or sharkd if your library is erroring unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

The `pcap abort 11` is not a valid capture/bpf filter.

I don't have experience with pcap4j but from [setFilter API documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.pcap4j/pcap4j/1.7.7/org/pcap4j/core/PcapHandle.html#setFilter(java.lang.String,%20org.pcap4j.core.BpfProgram.BpfCompileMode,%20java.net.Inet4Address)) it looks like it expects capture/bpf filters and not a Display filters.

The difference between Display and Capture filters is explained [here](https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/6660/what-is-the-difference-between-capture-filter-and-display-filter/6663).

As far as I know there is not capture/bpf filter that you could use to filter TCAP Abort messages.

A valid Display filters for Aborts are `tcap.dialogueAbort_element`, `tcap.abort_source` or `tcap.reason == 10 or tcap.reason == 11` but I don't know how to use them with pcap4j

An alternative to `pcap4j` for your use case could be decoding the capture with [tshark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) or [sharkd](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/sharkd), both programs support display filters and tshark supports JSON (`-T json`) and XML (`-T pdml`) output formats that you could easily process in Java.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks for your help